# What is the purpose of this query component in the HTML script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, http, caching

I was reading this source code:

https://github.com/leobalter/PimpMyCode/blob/master/index.html#L20

```
<script src="js/compiled.min.js?v=125" async></script>
```

If you get rid of the entire line the CodeMirror section will go away. But you can change the number to anything you want and the textbox will stay.

What's that **query** like `?v=125` doing?

I have never seen anyone using this.

Comment: You may have also seen the file names themselves be modified with a unique value, such as `js/compiled.min.v125.js`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It breaks the browsers cache (i.e. changes the url of the file that the browser uses to identify the cached file, forcing the browser to re-download the file whenever that query string value changes.)

This is useful when you want to deploy updates to the file and have all users get the changes immediately, rather than having to wait for their cache to clear or clear it manually.

The value itself is not significant.  It doesn't change the output, and the server doesn't use it.  It's there simply to force the browser to download the new version.

Comment: Thanks. I heard a lot about using header to expire the cache. If I were deploying a static site I can see the simpleness. Under what condition would I use the header?

Comment: The header is useful for forcing the browser to cache static assets for long periods of time, essentially the opposite of this.  The browser doesn't have to respect the header, but it does have to respect the query string.

Comment: I see. Is this technique documented anywhere? I am trying to find a documentation on this. If you can find it that would be great. Still trying.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a lot of people have asked this question after goolging "cache js css".

Comment: Yeah, its a common problem, and this is a common solution.

Comment: _"breaks the browser cache"_ is a misleading statement. New answer added.

Comment: It's not really misleading, It's just a common (slang, I suppose) phrase used to describe what is happening.  I've also heard it referred to as "Cache Busting".

Comment: @Kyle when explaining new concepts, idioms tend to get in the way of understanding. Clear, unambiguous wording is important.

Comment: @RickViscomi sure, that's fair.  I wouldn't call it a mistake though, just in need of clarification.

Comment: Added clarification to my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Static files like `.js` resources are usually configured to be cached by the browser for a long time (1 year). By using the resource in cache, the user experiences a much faster load time.

The conundrum is this: if the user has my JavaScript file in cache, how do I guarantee that the updated file is put to use by all users at once?

Enter the querystring parameter. `?v=125` is an identifier, probably a version number of some kind. When the resource is modified and released, this number (or string) will change to a new, unused value. Parameters appended to a resource name cause the resources to be handled like a brand new file by caches. So even though the user may have `script.js` or `script.js?v=124` in cache, `script.js?v=125` will be loaded directly from the server, with all of the latest and greatest code.

The accepted answer contains a strange phrase. *"It breaks the browsers cache"* sounds dangerous! It's okay because this is not *literally* what happens. The cache is fine. In fact, the old `?v=124` file is still there! The unique resource naming scheme simply causes a harmless **cache miss**.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. Yeah That was very helpful. Now that I think about it, I might have already seent his when I studied "High Performance Web Sites".